# Ada Enums to Values

Tags: enums, ada

I could handle this in a not as clean way, but I was hoping to take advantage of the following:

```ada
type Prefix is (Yocto, Zepto, Atto, Femto, Pico, Nano,
    Micro, Milli, Centi, Deci, None, Deca, Hecto, Kilo,
    Mega, Giga, Tera, Peta, Exa, Zetta, Yotta);
for Prefix use (
    Yocto => -24,
    Zepto => -21,
    Atto => -18,
    Femto => -15,
    Pico => -12,
    Nano => -9,
    Micro => -6,
    Milli => -3,
    Centi => -2,
    Deci => -1,
    None => 0,
    Deca => 1,
    Hecto => 2,
    Kilo => 3,
    Mega => 6,
    Giga => 9,
    Tera => 12,
    Peta => 15,
    Exa => 18,
    Zetta => 21,
    Yotta => 24);
```

GNAT doesn't complain about the representation clause. However, I can't seem to actually get the value out, since the only attributes related to this, that I am aware of, have to do with position, not assigned value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enumerations were never intended for this sort of purpose, and you shouldn't try to use them for that.  (I think the main purpose was to define enumerations that had values other than 0, 1, ... in some external representation or a hardware register or something.)  However, you can actually fix this while keeping your code almost the same:

```ada
type Prefix is (Yocto, Zepto, Atto, Femto, Pico, Nano,
    Micro, Milli, Centi, Deci, None, Deca, Hecto, Kilo,
    Mega, Giga, Tera, Peta, Exa, Zetta, Yotta);
type Prefix_To_Integer_Map is array (Prefix) of Integer;
Power_of_Ten : constant Prefix_To_Integer_Map := (
    Yocto => -24,
    Zepto => -21,
    Atto => -18,
    Femto => -15,
    Pico => -12,
    Nano => -9,
    Micro => -6,
    Milli => -3,
    Centi => -2,
    Deci => -1,
    None => 0,
    Deca => 1,
    Hecto => 2,
    Kilo => 3,
    Mega => 6,
    Giga => 9,
    Tera => 12,
    Peta => 15,
    Exa => 18,
    Zetta => 21,
    Yotta => 24);
```

Should be about as clean as what you had.  And saying `Power_Of_Ten (My_Prefix)` is more descriptive than `My_Prefix'Enum_Rep` or `Prefix'Enum_Rep(My_Prefix)` or whatever it is.

Comment: This seems to be the best way to do so in a vendor agnostic way. @trashgod has a good solution for those only working with GNAT.

Comment: @ajb  It's certainly clearer than Enum_Val, but the array allocation(static or dynamic)  for a simple operation is quite a resource penalty, especially for memory constrained runtime environments. It's unclear what the compiler will generate. Perhaps adding the constant optimized away the array alocation?

Answer (score 4):

If an implementation defined attribute is acceptable, GNAT provides two attributes that are useful in this context:

- [`Enum_Rep`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Attribute-Enum_005fRep.html#Attribute-Enum_005fRep), which "returns the representation value for the given enumeration value."
- [`Enum_Val`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Attribute-Enum_005fVal.html#Attribute-Enum_005fVal), which "returns the enumeration value whose representation matches the argument."

Answer (score 3):

The representation clause is used to set the internal value that is stored in memory for the type. If you want to get this value as an integer in a standard way, you should do an instantiation of the Unchecked_Conversion function.

```ada
with Ada.Unchecked_Conversion;
{...}

for Prefix'Size use Integer'Size;

function Value_of is new
   Ada.Unchecked_Conversion (Prefix, Integer);
```